# Suspend after lid is closed longer than X minutes

Tags: suspend, lid

is there a way to suspend my laptop if the lid is closed for more than X minutes?

I know only of suspend when lid is closed. Is there a easy way to add a delay?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 16 add this to auto run commands. 
This example delays on 20 minutes(s-seconds, d-days)

```
systemd-inhibit --what=handle-lid-switch sleep 20m
```